# How can I make a <g> grouping expand to 100% width and height?

Tags: css, svg

I am new to SVG and I'm trying to figure out how to make the `<g>` tag expand to 100% of the screen width and height. I have set the following:

HTML/svg:

```
<div class="full_size">
    <svg>
        <g>
            // stuff
        <g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.full_size {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

g {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The `<svg>` does expand to the full width and height. However, the `<g>` does NOT. How can I do this?

Comment: `<g>` can't do that. If you explain your requirement maybe we can suggest an alternative.